# Arduino Timer Library and void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, timer, arduino

I use this timer Library : https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer/tree/v2.1

code example :

```
int afterEvent = t.after(10000, doAfter, (void*)0);

void doAfter(void *context)
{
    Serial.println("stop the led event");
    t.stop(MyledEvent);
}
```

Documentation :

> > The context is a void pointer, so it can be cast to any other data
> >     type. Its use is optional, if you don't need it, just code (void*)0 as
> >     in the above examples, but be sure that the callback function
> >     definitions have it in their argument list
>
> int8_t after(unsigned long duration, void (*callback)(void*), void*
>   context);

I need to put a argument in "afterEvent" ( for futur use in "doAfter" ), I don't understand how to do this .Can you explain me how to do a argument list on  this "doAfter" and how to put the argument on "t.after" ?

My test :

```
int afterEvent = t.after(10000, doAfter(5), (void*)0);

void doAfter(int x, void *context)     { ..code... }
```

Error :

> error: declaration of ‘int type’ shadows a parameter
>
> error: arguments to function ‘void doAfter(int, void*)’error: too few

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need any parameters to your function then they need to be passed in via the context pointer that's what it is there for.  So a simple example might be the following:

```
void doAfter(void *my_param) {
     int x = *(int *)my_param;

     ..... your code here ...

}
```

And then to call it you would just do

```
const int input_param = 5;
int afterEvent = t.after(10000, doAfter, (void *)&input_param);
```

If you needed to pass more than one parameter then that can be done with a struct:

```
struct param_list {
     int param1;
     double param2;
};

void doAfter2(void *context)
{
      struct param_list *params = context;

      .... code here can access params with params-> ..

}

struct param_list p = {1, 2.0};
int afterEvent = t.after(10000, doAfter2, (void *)&p);
```

Comment: It's ok ! Thank you Dave.